# GOODPROB from codechef, what's the algo?

Tags: c++, math, logic

I was just solving problems and came upon this one

> Given an array A consisting of N integers - A1, A2....AN. You have to find the value of Σ MAX(i,j) * F(i,j) where 1 ≤ i < j ≤ N.
>
> MAX(i,j) is defined as max(Ai,Ai+1...Aj).
>
> F(i,j) is defined as:
>
> F(i,j) will be 1 if `(Ai&Aj) = Aj or (Ai&Aj) = Ai`
>   F(i,j) will be 0, otherwise.
>   Here & denotes the bitwise AND operator.

reference: [GOODPROB](https://www.codechef.com/problems/GOODPROB)

I wrote a fairly simple solution and got 40 points, i.e. it could not handle large inputs in the required 2 seconds time.

This was my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int max(int *A, int x,int y){
    int m=A[x];
    while(x<=y){
        if(A[x]>m)
            m=A[x];
        x++;
    }
    return m;
}

int F(int *A,int i,int j){
    return ((A[i]&A[j]) == A[j] or (A[i]&A[j]) == A[i])?1:0;
    }
int main() {
    long N;
    cin>>N;
    int *A = new int[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N; i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    long m=0;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        for(int i=0;i<j; i++)
            m+= F(A,i,j)?max(A,i,j)*F(A,i,j):0;
    cout<<m<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I checked the successful submitions there but those made me go panic. I couldn't even imagine such large solution for this fairly simple looking problem.
Can anyone come up with a solution simple enough to understand.

Comment: I believe using [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a lambda could provide a one liner solution for this. A plea: Please don't waste your time with online code judge engines, rather try to participate in some real world problems/projects.

Comment: Thanks but real world projects are quite long and I'm not completely prepared for them both in experience and time context.

Comment: _"I'm not completely prepared ..."_ You shouldn't believe that online code judges will prepare you in any way for these. You'll just learn bad habits. Working through some good books will make you prepared better a lot. We keep a list of good books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I've done a bit of freelancing. Actually online judges provide a good way to sharpen my maths skills (which I assume to be of importance in my future career of programming). They also provide the food for compition hunger.

Comment: @Hritik *Actually online judges provide a good way to sharpen my maths skills* -- `int *A = new int[N];`  This isn't math, this is a memory leak.  The online judges do nothing to help write quality C++ code.

Comment: Memory leak ? I wanted array of N elements so I did that. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

OK this does not really give you an effective algorithm but the comment section does not give the best formatting options.

I have found some small optimization possibilities. You repeat statements sometimes when not needed.

```
m+= F(A,i,j)?max(A,i,j)*F(A,i,j):0;
```

Here you can store the result of `F(A,i,j)` and only call this function twice (function calls can be expensive).

```
return ((A[i]&A[j]) == A[j] or (A[i]&A[j]) == A[i])?1:0;
```

Same here with `A[i]&A[j]`. You could store the result beforehand.

So just some small things in your current algorithm. How much they will help / improve you have to measure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the maximum value in range of array linearly. 
Doing this adds up **O(n)** factor in your overall complexity. And since you are using nested loops and calling max from inside these your overall time complexity will be **O(n^3)** .

You can reduce this factor significantly by using Segment Tree Data Structure.
Using segment tree you can find maximum in  a range within **O(log(n))** time.
Reducing Overall complexity to **O( n^2 * log(n) )**
For tutorial on Range Max/Min query

[Range Minimum Query using Segment Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/)